# Mod Rewrite Old Url to new

Tags: mod-rewrite

how can I mod rewrite this url

```
/search.php?name=thesearchname
```

to this structure

```
http:/mysite.com/search/a/1/thesearchname.html
```

mod rewrite in htaccess

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=(.+)
RewriteRule /search.php http://mysite.com/search/a/1/%1.html
```